# How to approach searching this theorized dataset with couchbase. Elastic search?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, view, couchbase, documents

My data set is pretty basic. Lets assume I have a document with device data, and I have additional documents with associated ports, hardware modules, etc. This data is larger than the 20MB document limit, and I also don't want to pull a huge document to make a change to small detail on a port anyway. Device details are kept in the device document, like its location, name, hardware type etc.

I can easily use views to get ports associated to a device, hardware pieces, etc. Thats no problem at all, parameterized views help with this basic listing. However, for a larger complex search I would have to either have a view for most popular values, and pull down entire documents for more complex searches, which gets unsustainable really fast. I would have to pull all devices in location dallas, and then pull all ports of type available for each device, pull the document if I want a detail thats not in the view, etc. Tons of memory consumption and slow.

Does elastic search provide the capabilities required to say, search for a document of type server with location dallas that has ten or more documents linked back to it of type port with status as available, media type fiber etc?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: you wanna restrict fields returning??

Comment: No, I'm more interested in either getting the full document contents, or just a document ID as I can then just pull it anyway.

Comment: But, I do need to be able to find a document which has other documents linking to it. A child document could have a parentId field with the master document ID. So I might want to find a master document that has the location property of dallas, that also has over ten child documents with a status property as available.